# Shortcut to disable keyboard/mouse in OSX

Tags: macos, keyboard, mouse

On more than a few instances, I have accidentally disabled the internal keyboard and trackpad by a shortcut.

The only button which works is the power-up key which I can use to wake up (if it's in sleep mode) and force quit by holding it.

My question is, **which** keyboard shortcut (or keyboard and mouse click combination) does this effect and what can you do to undo it? To reenable keyboard/mouse...

Answer (score 3):

This is a common problem for mac users, press the option key 5 times, and it will be fixed.

Source:
     http://www.mackungfu.org/cat-proofing-a-macbook-keyboard

Comment: Actually, I did attempt to press the option (alt) key 5 times and nothing happened. (I heard about this potential solution before).

Comment: Sorry... I don't know what else to do...

Comment: read the UPDATE section in the [link](http://www.mackungfu.org/cat-proofing-a-macbook-keyboard). It uses Karabiner